# Sometimes BMSPush registerDevice() doesn't respond in Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, ibm-cloud

I have this code which initializes BMSClient and BMSPush:

```
BMSClient.initialize(BMSClient.REGION_UK);

var options = {}
BMSPush.initialize(appGuid, clientSecret, options);

BMSPush.registerDevice({},
  function (status) {
    console.log(status);
  },
  function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

It's called in the AppComponent constructor (Ionic 2 app) when platform.ready(), but sometimes, for no apparent reason, registerDevice() doesn't respond neither with onSuccess nor with onError. Other times it works properly even in the same device.

Thanks in advance!